# About @InjectMocks and @Mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test requestListServiceImpl this class.It contains requestListDao.

RequestListServiceImpl Code

```
@Override
    public PageInfo<RequestList> getAllRequest(int startPage, int pageSize, String accountName,String userName) {
        PageHelper.startPage(startPage, pageSize);
        List<RequestList> list=requestListDao.getAllRequest(accountName,userName);
        for(RequestList requestList:list) {
            switch (requestList.getStatus()) {
            case "0":
                requestList.setStatus("Waiting");
                break;
            case "1":
                requestList.setStatus("Closed");        
                break;
            case "2":
                requestList.setStatus("Cancel");
                break;
            default:
                requestList.setStatus("NAN");
                break;
            }
        }
        PageInfo<RequestList> pageInfo = new PageInfo<RequestList>(list);
        return pageInfo;
    }

@Override
    public void createRequest(RequestList requestList) {
        Integer coount=requestListDao.getTime(requestList.getCreateName());
//      AWSSnsUtil.sendMassageToSns(requestList.getAccountName());
        requestList.setTime(++coount);
        requestListDao.createRequest(requestList);
    }
```

Test Code:

```
    @InjectMocks
    RequestListServiceImpl requestListServiceImpl;
    @Mock
    RequestListDao requestListDao;

 @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }


    @Test  //it's ok 
    public void testGetAllRequest() throws Exception {
        RequestList r=new RequestList();
        r.setStatus("0");
        when(requestListDao.getAllRequest(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(Arrays.<RequestList>asList(r));
        PageInfo<RequestList> res=requestListServiceImpl.getAllRequest(1,1,"1","1");
        Assert.assertNotNull(res);


    }

 @Test   //this test is error, the error is requestListServiceImpl is not mock.
    public void testCreateRequest() throws Exception {
        when(requestListDao.getTime(anyString())).thenReturn(0);
        RequestList r=new RequestList();
        r.setCreateName("demo");
        requestListServiceImpl.createRequest(r);
        verify(requestListServiceImpl).createRequest(r);

    }
```

Error info

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type RequestListServiceImpl and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
```

When i change @InjectMocks to @Mock, The second test it's ok ,but first test it's error.
I need add to a stubbing `when(requestListServiceImpl.getAllRequest(anyInt(),anyInt(),anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(new PageInfo<>());`

I don't know how to do it,

Is injectmocks necessary？

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
verify(requestListServiceImpl)
```

And

```
@InjectMocks
RequestListServiceImpl requestListServiceImpl;
```

The message is pretty clear: you **verify** **mock** objects that Mockito created for you.

@InjectMocks does **not** create mocks. It rather **injects** mocks that you have in your test class **into** a real object.

So, what is necessary here: read the manual or a tutorial. Meaning: don't start with Mockito by applying it immediately to your project. Instead, step back, and look at simple examples to understand *how* it is supposed to be used.

In your current setup: `requestListServiceImpl` is a real object. So you should check if that class offers you methods to **verify** its internal status. You triggered some action on it, but because it is a real object, Mockito doesn't know what you did. But how to actually solve this depends on YOUR code base.

Comment: Do you mean I can do this? \n``` @Test public void testCreateRequest() throws Exception { doReturn(1).when(requestListDao).getTime(anyString()); int res=requestListDao.getTime("1"); Assert.assertEquals(1,res); }```

Comment: Hint: dont ask for permission. GO TRY YOURSELF. You learn best by trying. And again: better step back. Instead of trying to combine Mockito with your setup **first** learn how mockito works. If I remember correctly, that DAO object is a MOCK. There is no point in "verifying" mock objects themselves. So a test that only touches a MOCK doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test `requestListServiceImpl` you should use @InjectMocks so mockito calls the real method on `requestListServiceImpl`. When you use @Mock, the method will by default not be invoked.
`@InjectMocks` will be the same as if you create it yourself with `new requestListServiceImpl(mock(requestListDao))`

When you use `verify(mock).someMethod();` you have to pass a mock to that method, not @InjectMocks.
You want to verify if a certain method is called on a mock inside your class under test(`requestListServiceImpl`).

Instead of @InjectMocks there is also @Spy, which will kinda do both, you can mock methods in `requestListServiceImpl` but also call the real method.

Comment: Do you mean I can do this?
```
  @Test
    public void testCreateRequest() throws Exception {
        doReturn(1).when(requestListDao).getTime(anyString());
        int res=requestListDao.getTime("1");
        Assert.assertEquals(1,res);

    }```